# Unable to locate package referenceassemblies-pcl

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, mono, package, apt-get

I am on Ubuntu and I am entering the following command in my terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -y binutils mono-complete ca-certificates-mono referenceassemblies-pcl fsharp
```

This fails, giving the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package referenceassemblies-pcl
```

I have googled this error and found some people suggesting to make the referenceassemblies-pcl available by doing the following, which intuitively makes sense:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/ppa
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~referenceassemblies-pci/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~referenceassemblies-pci' user or team does not exist.
```

How can I get my initial command to work? I presume I need to install/download referenceassemblies-pcl somehow but I can't find anywhere explaining how to do this that works for me.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Ubuntu questions usually go to its own site, https://askubuntu.com/questions/647808/unable-to-locate-mono-packages-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by following the instructions on how to install mono on the actual mono website. I was following the instructions in the Lean Engine github readme and these appear to have been incorrect or out dated.